# How do I fix Import Error: libstdc++.so.6 error, GLIBCXX 3.4.26

Tags: linux, gcc, gnu-make, paraview

I am getting this error when running ParaView:

> "ImportError:
> /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6:
> version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)"

I don't know anything about how to solve this problem, I looked online and tried to download and update and when I run the command I get the following:

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX

GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: GLIBCXX_3.4.26 is an object in libstdc++.so.6.0.26 ← GCC 9.1.0 https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html ............ So you will have to point to a `libstdc++.so.6 ->libstdc++.so.6.0.26` which is old enough to work with your unknown OS. Please add OS name, version to your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69044710/edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [libstdc++.so.6: version \`GLIBCXX\_3.4.20' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773296/libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found)

Comment: Does [https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error) answer your question?