# Problem with installation of R packages on ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I just installed the latest R version (4.1.1 (2021-08-10)) on my Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. I tried to install some packages. I started with stringi and I have the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringi’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/stringi/libs/stringi.so)
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/stringi’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpXRZprI/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("stringi") :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried to install libraries as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923209/problems-installing-the-devtools-package)

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

however it didn't help. I'm total newbie in such installations and ubuntu libraries. Could you give me a hint how to solve this problem I also want to install `devtools` (same problem).

Comment: I do not use Ubuntu, but Fedora instead. On Fedora, there is a repository from which to install the R binaries packages (no compilation needed) -- this approach is much more practical and convenient. I guess the corresponding repository for Ubuntu can be found here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the sollution.

First, I reinstalled R (however I think it's optional).
Then other error occured, namely something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219839/issues-installing-r-base-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies). Commenting particular line in sources.list finally allowed to instal R. After this I got the same error as above. I was unable to install particular packages. I decided to take closer look to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.29 not found`. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773296/libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found). I typed the commands provided in top voted answers anfter days of struggle it finally worked and all packages have been installed!