# Google Cloud VM: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, debian-based, debian-buster

I am using Google cloud vm where
lsb-release gives:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

I am running my script but its giving this error:

> ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
> `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/_max_len_seq_inner.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

I am not running it on conda but it still mentions required by conda.
I am stuck on finding `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' version.

I tried the methods mention here: [libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773296/libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found) but i still not get 3.4.26 version.

here are the versions i have :
using

> strings /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Also this library is under /usr/lib and /lib both, but both of them dont have 3.4.26 version.
Please help in finding the right way to install the latest version.

Comment: Unusual easy: Repack the Debian 11 libstdc++6_10.2.1-6 to require "no 'gcc-10-base' dependency". New version = `libstdc++6_10.2.1-28_amd64.deb` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZfJfvzbqrCu6M9VtQ0NHLr6PIf3KXk1K/view?usp=sharing .... Install (with gdebi), and you have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.28`, i.e. GLIBCXX_3.4.28 etc. all GLIBCXX objects  _3.4 up.